# How to distribute custom xcode templates to developers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am working on creating custom project templates using xcode 8.2.1. I know how to create a custom project template but my question is how do i distribute this to other developers. I cannot ask developers to copy paste the template folder i created every time in the Xcode templates path. Also maintaining template versions will be difficult. Instead is there any option to save my template code somewhere and upon clicking some installer it automatically download the dependencies and paste it in xcode template folder?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you upload your code to github and everytime anyone wants to use it just have to clone the repo?

Comment: My requirement is to create a project template so that every time developer choose my project template, automatically all the relevant files get added to the xcode project.